# Selenium crashes when there is another browser window open

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Recently I started playing around with Selenium and I've been trying to scrape some data from some websites using it in Python; automating Chrome. Initially I ran Selenium without specifying the profile to use, until I found out I could use a pre-existing profile. I created a profile just for this purpose. But I've come to notice when there is another browser window opened, Selenium opens a new browser window using the set profile, as desired, but then crashes. If there are no any other chrome sessions running, it does not crash. When running headless chrome, program does not crash regardless of whether there are other chrome sessions running or not.

This is the error message thrown:

```
File "C:\Users\Guy\pyvenv\WebAutoPyQt6\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
(No symbol) [0x0087DCE31
```

I looked it up and all I could find was to add **--disable-dev-shm-usage** and **--no-sandbox** to the chrome options
`options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")`
`options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")`
But this didn't help

So my question and how can I bypass this problem? For now all I'm doing is closing all other chrome sessions before running the test, when I forget, I encounter that problem!
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

PS:
I'm using windows 10 pro, Chrome version 111.0.5563.111 (Official Build) (64-bit), ChromeDriver version 111.0.5563.64, Selenium version 4.1.3, Python version 3.9.10

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import os

class Bot(webdriver.Chrome):
  def __init__(self, driverpath: str, datadir: str, **kwargs):
    """create a bot to surf chrome browser\n
    @param driverpath: absolute path to the chrome driver\n
    @param datadir: absolute path to folder where to store data by the bot\n
    ---
    @kwparam headless: if `True` run chrome virtually, otherwise launch chrome browser window\n
    @kwparam user_agent: the user agent to use; useful if running headless\n
    @kwparam user_data_dir: absolute path to chrome `User Data` folder\n
    @kwparam profile_name: name of folder of the chrome profile"""

    super(Bot, self).__init__(service=Service(executable_path=driverpath),
                              options=Bot.create_options(**kwargs),
                              desired_capabilities=Bot.create_desired_caps())
    self.datadir = datadir

  @property
  def datadir(self):
    return self.__datadir

  @datadir.setter
  def datadir(self, dir_: str):
    if not os.path.exists(dir_):
      os.makedirs(dir_)

    self.__datadir = dir_

  @staticmethod
  def create_options(**kwargs) -> Options:
    """create chrome options to alter preferences\n
    @kwparam headless: if `True` run chrome virtually, otherwise launch chrome browser window\n
    @kwparam user_agent: the user agent to use; useful if running headless\n
    @kwparam user_data_dir: absolute path to chrome `User Data` folder\n
    @kwparam profile_name: name of folder of the chrome profile"""

    options = Options()
    options.headless = kwargs.get('headless', False)
    if not (user_data_dir := kwargs.get("user_data_dir")) is None and os.path.isdir(user_data_dir):
      if not (profile := kwargs.get('profile_name')) is None and os.path.isdir(f'{user_data_dir}\\{profile}'):
        options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={user_data_dir}")
        options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory={profile}')
    if not (user_agent := kwargs.get("user_agent")) is None:
      options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')
    # options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    return options

  @staticmethod
  def create_desired_caps() -> dict:
    '''alters desired capabilities to set in the driver\n
    ---
    @rtype dict: dict containing the altered capabilities'''

    caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
    caps['pageLoadStrategy'] = 'eager'
    caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
    return caps

def test():
  os.system('cls')
  # globalz_test()

  bot = Bot(driverpath=PATH.EXEFile_chromedriver_v111, # C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe
            datadir=PATH.DIR_data, # C:/path/to/some/folder
            user_agent=SETUPCONFIG.constant.chrome_user_agent, # Mozilla.../Chrome/..
            user_data_dir=SETUPCONFIG.constant.chrome_user_data_dir, # C:/path/to/chrome/User Data
            profile_name=SETUPCONFIG.constant.chrome_profile_name, # Profile 4
            headless=False)
  input('press any key to continue...')
```

Comment: Did you make sure that they don't use the same profile path? Check using `chrome://version/`

Comment: Yep, Executable Path is same, for all profiles, but the Profile Path for each is different

Comment: In that case, try running chrome with the flags you provided standalone from command line, without using Selenium. Then check the error message and provide it in your question.

Comment: If by flags you mean using switches on cmd, I've done that. Only tried with **--user-data-dir**, **--profile-directory** and **--start-maximized**. I'm receiving no output at all but the behavior is still the same. I know this because the window does not maximize when there are other chrome sessions running, same same behavior as with selenium

Comment: So that would make me assume there's an issue with running 2 different profiles on the same time?